# joomla: editing html of menus?

Tags: html, css, joomla

is it possible for me to edit the html of the menus on top here?

http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=1&Itemid=27

the home, buying property, selling property, etc, want to be able to edit the html. is that possible? where would the file be?

i actually need them to take up 100% of the top and to be spaced in such a manner that when you add more menus they will just get smaller because they would always take up the entire top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial helps you: [How To Edit Joomla Templates - part 1](http://www.ultijoomla.com/blog/How-To-Edit-Joomla-Templates-part-1.html).

Or read to [official documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla%21_1.5_Template_Tutorial) for editing templates.

Comment: Meh! My bad...sorry I misunderstood the question... my apologies... :( Have removed my answer and comments...

Comment: sure felix I can undo it...again I'm embarrassed!

Comment: No problemo. And no you weren't sounding 'rude' or angry... :D